# NodeJS readdir and require relative paths

Tags: node.js, module

Let's say I have this directory structure

```
/Project
   /node_modules
      /SomeModule
         bar.js
   /config
      /file.json
   foo.js
```

-

```
foo.js:
require('bar');
```

-

```
bar.js:
fs.readdir('./config'); // returns ['file.json']
var file = require('../../../config/file.json');
```

Is it right that the readdir works from the file is being included (foo.js) and require works from the file it's been called (bar.js)?

Or am I missing something?
Thank you

Comment: `fs.readdir()` interprets relative paths according to `process.cwd()` while `require()` interprets relative paths according to `__dirname`.

Answer (score 18):

As [Dan D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388787/dan-d) expressed, fs.readdir uses `process.cwd()` as start point, while `require()` uses `__dirname`. If you want, you can always resolve from one path to another, getting an absolute path both would interpret the same way, like so:

```
var path = require('path');
route = path.resolve(process.cwd(), route);
```

That way, if using `__dirname` as start point it will ignore `process.cwd()`, else it will use it to generate the full path.

For example, assume `process.cwd()` is `/home/usr/node/`:

- if `route` is `./directory`, it will become `/home/usr/node/directory`
- if `route` is `/home/usr/node/directory`, it will be left as is

I hope it works for you :D

Comment: This code is very hard to follow. Where is `route` defined? Do you have a better way of expressing `fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, './path/', cb)` ?

Comment: `route` is what you want to open (in your case it would be `./path/`). You can always use `readdirSync` to avoid using callback. Also, you are missing a `)` after `'./path/'`

Comment: This! This right here is exactly what I wanted to know. Took me a while to find the information. I would never have guessed about `process.cwd()` by myself, guess I should have read more of the docs.